# Unix - Oracle : How to remove CR at the end of file

Tags: oracle, unix, csv, carriage-return

I generate a csv file (example.csv) using an oracle procedure (utl_file.put_line), but when i open the file with notepad, i realize that there is an CR (carriage return) at the end of the file. I just want to remove that CR.

The file is generated on a server UNIX (AIX), and i open it on my computer (windows) using  notepad.

Thanks fo your help

Comment: Unix? Notepad?  Something doesn't add up here.

Answer (score 3):

This seems the wrong way around. Newline in Unix is line feed (LF) and on Windows is carriage-return line feed (CRLF).

If you're creating a file in Unix and opening it in Windows I would expect few problems as Windows normally works out that you meant newline by LF. If you're doing it the other way around, generating the file in Windows and opening in Linux you should probably expect a stray character on the end of each line.

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/package.htm#TTPLS294) says that `utl_file.put_line` *"appends an operating system-specific line terminator."* This means that the problems you're experiencing make little sense. There should be a LF on the end of each line. Furthermore, even if Oracle was doing this incorrectly and appending a Windows newline it'll be CRLF.

It *may* be that Notepad for some reason is appending a CR on the end, though this doesn't really make much sense.

A work around, if you're always going to be viewing the file in windows is to use `utl_file.put`, which doesn't include the operating system specific newline on the end and concatenate CRLF on the end.

Something line, `utl_file.put( filename, theline || chr(13) || chr(10) );` where [`chr(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions026.htm#SQLRF00616) returns the character with the values *n* in your character set. 13 is the Ascii for carriage return and 10 for new line.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most common way to solve this problem is using this tool unix2dos. Run this command on your unix box and then open new_example.csv file on your window

here is the command for you:

```
unix2dos -n example.csv new_example.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending Ben's answer:

You can also use `utl_file.put_line( filename, theline || chr(13));`

The output is the same [CR][LF] at the end of the line.